# kohana user login adding error

Tags: forms, validation, authentication, kohana

I have following login code:

```
if ($logged == true) {
                HTTP::redirect('profile/private');
            } else {
                $validation = Validation::factory($_POST)
                        ->rule('username', 'not_empty')
                        ->rule('password', 'not_empty');
                if ($validation->check()) {

                }
                $errors = $validation->errors('login');
```

The case here is if no username is entered, the proper message will be sown (I have messages in login.php file in messages folder for example: 'username' => array('not_empty' => 'Field :field can not be empty', the same for password field). And theese two rules are working properly with errors.
But when both username and password are given and user is not authenticated as 'valid' (for example wrong password or mistyped username) I need one custom error message (for example: 'Check username or password, Maybe CAPSLOCK is pressed'). How to achieve this? What with error message i don't want it to be related with just one field like all messages in login.php field. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then answering your question: this is a extra error message for user purposes. This is not a specific error on one or your model's properties (username, password), so this belongs in your controller.

Just in your controller, check if user is logged in and echo the error.

```
if (!Auth::instance()->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['autologin'])) 
{
    echo 'Check username or password, Maybe CAPSLOCK is pressed';
}
```

Comment: I did it this way in registration action and it is working great, but i need to do login validation. When i check this: $logged = Auth::instance()->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['autologin'] = false) i have only true or false. I need to give user a message like this: "Check username or password, Maybe CAPSLOCK is pressed", which is not related with any particular field (i think so).

Comment: Then you don't need validation at all. Just check if $logged === false and then echo the error.

Comment: I think it is best aproach. I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Validation#errors) if you call $validation->errors() with no template defined, it will give you an array of errors back,   then you can look thru the $errors array and determine what kinds of errors you get, and react appropriately

Comment: $validation->errors() is null after check() method. I don't know if i can get errors from $logged = Auth::instance()->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['autologin'] = false). I think i can add error to for example username field with index lets say 'general' and this will work, but it is not sure that error is generated by username. So from this point it will be wrong. I found this aproach here: https://github.com/mixu/useradmin so i think it is ok for use.